# Multiple group_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models :

```
dimension_mois 
Admin::Style
Admin::Album
```

They are related like that :

```
**DimensionMois**
has_many :admin_styles, :class_name=>"Admin::Style"

**Admin::Style**
has_many :admin_albums, :class_name=>"Admin::Album"

**Admin::Album**
belongs_to :admin_style, :class_name=>"Admin::Style"
belongs_to :dimension_mois
```

The concept of the page is to show something like that :

[image: Schema of what I want]

I would like to show this for each month. Each month could have N styles. Each style could hve N albums.

I have no idea about the way to do that. I've tried with group_by, but  the results are never good.

Any idea ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be overthinking the problem. I believe you just need to iterate over the objects and their associations, like so:

```
@dimension_moises = DimensionMois.includes(:admin_styles => :admin_albums)
// Using Haml syntax
%ul
  - @dimension_moises.each do |dimension_mois|
    %li
      = dimension_mois.name
      %ul
        - dimension_mois.admin_styles.each do |admin_style|
          %li
            = admin_style.name
            %ul
              - admin_style.admin_albums.each do |admin_album|
                %li= admin_album.title
```

That will give you a nested, hierarchical list of all the DimensionMois with the Admin::Styles and Admin::Albums for that object. You can use CSS, JS, whatever to style that list.